# Creating New Roles Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, roles

i been studying in how to add role this website http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/roles/creating-and-managing-roles-cs

i lost at step 4. Creating New Roles..

```
  protected void CreateRoleButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string newRoleName = RoleName.Text.Trim(); if (!Roles.RoleExists(newRoleName)) // Create the role 
           Roles.CreateRole(newRoleName); RoleName.Text = string.Empty; 
    }
```

after i done do what it said .. i got this Error :The name 'Roles' does not exist in the current context..

What did i miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you follow, *Step 2: Specifying and Configuring the Roles Framework Provider* and *Step 3: Examining the Roles API* ? Please ensure that your codebehind references *System.Web.Security* namespace.

Above steps make sure that all configuration are taken place to implement role-based authentication.

For more information, see [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.aspx) which explains full configuration for roles impelementation.